# What is a good way measure voltage considering accidental polarity reversal?

Tags: circuit-design, voltage-measurement

Hypothetically, if a circuit is potentially exposed to accidental polarity reversal (i.e. when a user connects positive to negative, and negative to positive by accident): When measuring the voltage using a voltage divider, I assume that the component which is receiving the voltage measurement signal will then be potentially exposed to reverse current.

Is the solution to still use a voltage divider and place a diode on the measuring component's ground connection, or should a voltage follower op amp be used to provide current isolation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is usually to size the resistors in the potential divider such that the current flowing in the op-amp pin (due to reverse voltage) is below about 1 mA but, in any case check the data sheet for the op-amp because this limit value is usually stated.